# c++: Can std::queue replace the ring buffer

Tags: c++, performance, data-structures, queue

I know that Ring Buffer is an useful data structure, its performance is great.

I'm thinking if `std::queue` in C++ - STL can replace the Ring Buffer, meaning that if `std::queue` has the same performance with the Ring Buffer.

For example, I'm thinking if making a class as below to achieve a Ring Buffer easily:

```
template<typename T>
class RingBuffer
{
    std::queue<T> q;
    size_t MAX_SIZE;
};
```

Then I use the `MAX_SIZE` to init the `q`.

Is this the same thing with the standard Ring Buffer?

Comment: Default container of [queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue) is a [deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) and the allocated memory is not all contiguous. That may have some performance implications.

Comment: How about abstract over the type (type signature) then profile the code. If performance is an issue then just plug new buffer?

Comment: @MutableSideEffect   Do you think there is some way to make the allocated memory for `deque` contiguous? You see I set the `MAX_SIZE` is to try to achieve such a goal but I'm not sure if it is possible.

Comment: I don't think there is anything in the standard library. The interface of std::queue is in such a way that you need to be able to freely remove and add elements (both from front and back) without any MAX_SIZE limit. This makes std::queue different from your use case. Boost provides [Circular Buffer](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html) which is probably what you want.

Comment: @MutableSideEffect  Alright, so I guess Boost is a choice.